# StencilJS Click method not getting called

Tags: stenciljs

while trying the example code from `stenciljs` doc - https://stenciljs.com/docs/templating-jsx, I'am facing one issue. The click event handler is not getting triggered at all.

```
import { Component, h } from '@stencil/core';
@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  shadow: true
})

export class MyComponent {
  handleClick(event: UIEvent) {
    alert('Received the button click!');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={ (event: UIEvent) => this.handleClick(event)}>Click Me!</button>
    );
  }
}
```

--index.html code--

```
<my-component></my-component>
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code, and it works fine for me. Maybe try logging to the console in case something is blocking popups.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Polyfills in case that your Browser has issues with ES6 syntax e.g.

```
npm run build --es5
```